# Postgresql SELECTing from JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Assume I am using PG 9.3 and I have a post table with a json column 'meta_data':

Example content of the json column 'meta_data'

```
{
  "content": "this is a post body",
  "comments": [
    {
      "user_id": 1,
      "content": "hello"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 2,
      "content": "foo"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 3,
      "content": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I find all the posts where the user_id = 1 from the comments array from the meta_data column?

Comment: Looks to me like this would be rather better suited to traditionally relational modelling. Limited json support in Pg doesn't mean you should use json where regular relations will do just as well.

Comment: I should mention, the example is just a very over simplified version of the problem. In reality the JSON is much more complicated

Comment: are you able to add the plv8 extension?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive I'm implementing this incorrectly but try this

```
select * 
from posts 
where id in (
    select id from (
        select id, 
            json_array_elements(meta_data->'comments')->'user_id' as user_id
        from posts
    ) x 
    where cast(user_id as varchar) = '1'
);
```

There's probably an array operator like `@>` that will remove the need for the nested select statements but I can't seem to get it to work right now.

Let me know if this is going down the correct track, I'm sure we could figure it out if required.